# Cross-validation: matching folds when comparing two algorithms

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation, model-comparison

I want to compare two algorithms using cross-validation on the same dataset.

Should the data in each fold match across the two models? (i.e. training set of fold i of model 1 = training set of fold i of model 2)

Comment: Ideally yes, but if the holdout set in each fold is too small, the estimates of generalization error may be noisy.

Comment: My intuition is that if one algorithm performs better than the other, then the estimated error averaged over training sets should also be higher.